# VSCode rust format on save line length

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

```json
    "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command": "clippy",
    "[rust]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
```

I have these rust settings in vscode. They work fine for formatting, but the line length is shorter than I'd like. Is there a way I can adjust the max line length?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put a rustfmt.toml at the project root (rust-analyzer respects it), and use [rustfmt settings](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/):

```ini
max_width = <number you'd like>
```

Comment: It only works as an integer ( no quotes )

Comment: @BrandonKauffman Ah, thanks. Fixed (I didn't check).

Comment: is there a way to do this globally in vscode?

Edit:
found a way, just add this line to vscode settings.json:
```json
"rust-analyzer.rustfmt.extraArgs": ["--config", "max_width=80"],
```